# How can I format a value as a percentage without the percent sign?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, tostring

```
float f = 0.479f;
Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("p1"));
```

The output: 47.9 %

What should I pass to ToString() in order to remove the percentage sign for output like this:

> 47.9

EDIT.  I should have mentioned that I am passing the mask to a 3rd party component that does it's thing with it.  I can't perform any acrobatics with the numbers unfortunately.  It has to be the mask that does the trick.

Comment: what your 3rd component do with formatted string? does it limit your formatted text length?

Comment: @Rubens Because it simply provides a .FormatString property which takes this mask.  All the formatting is done by the 3rd party control.

Comment: Can you create a new NumberInfoFormat? If so, check my edited post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I should have mentioned that I am
>   passing the mask to a 3rd party
>   component that does it's thing with
>   it. I can't perform any acrobatics
>   with the numbers unfortunately. It has
>   to be the mask that does the trick.

So I assume that you are stuck with `Float.ToString(String)`, and that you cant only edit the `p1` in `f.ToString("p1")`. Now that's a tricky one. If you're not afraid of breaking anything related to the changes implied, you could do the following:

The "P" numeric format, as documented [On MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString), uses `NumericFormatInfo.PercentSymbol` in order to write the "%" sign. `NumericFormatInfo` is a member of your current `CultureInfo`. What you could do, is clone your `CurrentCulture`, and modify the PercentSymbol to `""` like the following:

```
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            float f = 0.479f;
            Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("p1")); //will write 47.9%

            CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
            ci.NumberFormat.PercentSymbol = "";            

            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
            Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("p1")); //will write 47.9

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

        }
    }
```

This would be the way to go if you don't want to alter the ToString call.

Comment: +1, seems to be most reliable method in OP scenario; maybe he will need to alter current culture directly and restore its default value after that 3rd-party component call.

Answer (score 5):

```
Console.WriteLine((f * 100).ToString("0.0"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Could try

```
Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("p1").Replace('%',' '));
```

Or, if you want don't want a space, use `Replace('%','\0')`

EDIT: If you can only use the `ToString()` method, you could create a `NumberFormatInfo` object, set the percentage symbol to be blank and pass it into the method. 
(`NumberFormatInfo` is in the `System.Globalization` namespace)
e.g.

```
    NumberFormatInfo myNewFormat = new NumberFormatInfo();
    myNewFormat.PercentSymbol = "";

    float f = 0.479f;

    Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("p1",myNewFormat));
```

Comment: For bonus globalisation points, use `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.PercentSymbol` rather than hardwiring the `%` symbol.  (I have no idea if any of the .NET cultures *actually* use a different symbol, though!)  Some cultures also place a space between the number and the `%` symbol (see `NumberFormatInfo.PercentPositivePattern`) so he may also want to perform a Trim after doing this or he'll be left with a leading or trailing space.

Answer (score 2):

How about just the following?

```
Console.WriteLine((f * 100).ToString("F1"));
```

e.g. f = 0.4792 --> "47.9"

A list and descriptions of standard numeric format are available [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), in case it helps.